# Unit Tests w/ Full Stack Traces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

This seems like a stupid question, but I could not find the answer anywhere. I am using Rails 3.1 with Test::Unit.

When a test fails I only see the top of the stack, e.g.:

```
ERROR creating a message sends emails (1.35s) 
          NoMethodError: undefined method `project' for nil:NilClass
      /Users/ghempton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@gt/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
```

How do I see the full stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wound up fixing this by updating the `turn` gem which formats the test output.

Answer (score 27):

uncomment the following line in config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb:

```
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!
```

funny that we've lived with this helpful option so long, I even forgot about it! :-)

Comment: It worked for me and may be a more general answer when not using a specific gem like turn. Plus, I'm new here and could use the bone. :-)

Comment: Bone given. I think `rails new` automatically adds turn, however.

Comment: Thanks for the bone and the tip on `turn` -- you're right, Rails appears to add it to new projects.

Comment: The tip worked on my Rails 2.3 project which was lacking the initializer, thanks.

Comment: This actually didn't work for me at the time... I have since switched entirely to rspec.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using the [minitest-reporters](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters) gem.

```
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!
```

did not work for my integration tests.